# How do I convert my asynctask to Rxjava?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am trying to convert the following 2 asynctasks to rxjava, but not sure how to go about it. Any ideas? :

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    /* Shutdown video players */
                    Set<Map.Entry<String, PlayerBundle>> entries = videoPlayerPool.entrySet();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, PlayerBundle> entry : entries) {
                        PlayerBundle bundle = entry.getValue();
                        bundle.player.release();
                    }

                    /* Shutdown audio players */
                    entries = audioPlayerPool.entrySet();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, PlayerBundle> entry : entries) {
                        PlayerBundle bundle = entry.getValue();
                        bundle.player.release();
                    }

                    videoStreamer.stopStream();
                    videoStreamer.release();

                    audioStreamer.stopStream();
                    audioStreamer.release();

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    cb.event(new Spin.Event<Void>());
                }
            }.execute();
```

and :

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Set<Map.Entry<String, Participant>> entries = pool.entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Participant> entry : entries) {
                    Participant participant = entry.getValue();
                    participant.release();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                cb.event(new Spin.Event<Void>());
            }
        }.execute();
```

I have already included the rxjava in my gradle, but not sure how to go about converting this

Comment: Try this https://piercezaifman.com/converting-an-asynctask-to-rxjava/ and ask real questions when you run into a problem. Keyword "TRY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Void> call() {
            /* Shutdown video players */
            Set<Map.Entry<String, PlayerBundle>> entries = videoPlayerPool.entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry<String, PlayerBundle> entry : entries) {
                PlayerBundle bundle = entry.getValue();
                bundle.player.release();
            }

            /* Shutdown audio players */
            entries = audioPlayerPool.entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry<String, PlayerBundle> entry : entries) {
                PlayerBundle bundle = entry.getValue();
                bundle.player.release();
            }

            videoStreamer.stopStream();
            videoStreamer.release();

            audioStreamer.stopStream();
            audioStreamer.release();

            return Observable.just(null);
        }
    })
    .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            cb.event(new Spin.Event<Void>());
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe();

    Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Void> call() {
            Set<Map.Entry<String, Participant>> entries = pool.entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Participant> entry : entries) {
                Participant participant = entry.getValue();
                participant.release();
            }
            return Observable.just(null);
        }
    }).doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            cb.event(new Spin.Event<Void>());
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: the above 2 are 2 different asynctasks. Is it possible to do them separately. Also, whats func0 and action0. Is it not possible to do them like an anonymous class? or standalone

Comment: second task converted the same way. Func0 and Action0 are anonymous classes. These are interface names

Comment: It gives me an error : cannot resolve symbol func0 and Action0 . any idea how to fix this?

Comment: make sure you have this imports: import rx.functions.Action0;
import rx.functions.Func0;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

Comment: is it doOnCompleted or doon complete? Also, I was just implementing :     implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1' , do I need to implement: implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14' too?

Comment: this is Java code. Java rx version: 1.3.0. names could be different.

Comment: I keep getting error on action0 as observable cannot be applied to anonymous rx.function

Comment: will this be fine : .doOnComplete(new Action() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() throws Exception {
                                      cb.event(new Spin.Event<Void>());
                                  }
                              }
                )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe();

Comment: sorry, my bad, was working fine with rxjava, i was actually using rx2

Comment: Since you don't update your UI, you can use Completable instead of Observable